# Compare one string of first file to all strings of second file, in Java

Tags: java, string, compare

In Java.

I have 2 PDF files,
I extract the Title from the first file, and the reference part from the second file.

I want to check if the all the title part is in the reference part or not.

My problem is how to take all the title part as one variable then search it in all the reference part.

This is the part of the code:

```
PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();    
String a = pdfUtil.getText("9.pdf");
String Title = a.substring(0,68);                        
System.out.println("The title part: "+Title);

String b = pdfUtil.getText("333.pdf");   
String Refer = b.substring(b.indexOf("Reference")+0,b.length());
if ("Reference".equalsIgnoreCase("Reference")) {    
            System.out.println("The References part of the second file is: "+Refer);
            System.out.println();
  }

   if (Title.contains(Refer)) {
    System.out.println("Found ");
        }
```

the output part:
The title part: Customized Efficient Collection of Big Data for Advertising Services
The References part of the second file is: [1] J. Han, H. Pei, and Y. Yin.” Mining, Frequent Patterns without Candidate Generation” In: Proc. (all the refernce part)

I try a lot of methods, but the output is always false, even if the exact title part is in the reference part.
Any Idea?

and is there another method than (contains) to search?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope `Title` and `Refer` are `String`. Then what is the point in creating new String using `StringBuilder` ? In other words your whole code is equivalent to `Refer.contains(Title)`

Comment: I made mistake in the code, now I edit it. Yes all is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

``could you please add more details but  in genral 
the main problem could be
1. extra space in one of the 2 strings 
like : "abcd"    "abcd " 
this 2 strings are not equal

2. the strings are not extracted correctly so could you please add  more details about how  you ate extracting data from pdf
3. if  the strings are not english you have problem with encoding

here is a code it might help

```
        String a="stack overflow";
        String b="tack";

        // solution 1 

        System.out.println(a.contains(b));




    // soultion 2

        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<a.length();j++)
            {
                if(b.substring(i,i+1).equals(a.substring(j,j+1)))
                {

                    counter++;
                }
            }

        }
        if(counter>=b.length())
        {
            System.out.println("string found ");
        }
        counter=0;
    // solution 3   fuzzy one 
        int index=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++)
        {
            index=a.indexOf(b.substring(i,i+1));
            if(index!=-1)
            {
                counter++;

            }



        }
        if(counter<b.length())
        {

            System.out.println("string not found ");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("string found ");
        }
```

solution 2 and 3 are working  main problem in the method
String.contains(String)
is the size of the 2 strings   example   a.contains(b)
 if size of a is smaller that size of b it will return false to get around this problem you can first check size of 2 strings before using .contains

```
if(a.length()>=b.length())
        {


        System.out.println(a.contains(b));
        }
```

this is 5th solution it will work  try it

```
            String a="Iam in the world of abc";
        String b="world";

  for(int i=0;i<a.length()-b.length();i++)
  {
   //System.out.println(i);

    if(a.substring(i,b.length()+i).equals(b))
  {
     System.out.println("true s");
     System.out.println(a.substring(i,b.length()+i));
  }


        }
```

Comment: The string all in English, and extracted correctly, but i can get the output correctly.  I edit the code.

Comment: bad solution but it will work is brude force  2 for loops  and compare 2 strings to each other

Comment: can you give me a brief example? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I try the first one, and give me false when: String a="stack overflow";
    String b="example stack overflow"; even when a in b. and this is my problem, how can I solve it ?

Comment: Yes, the 2 and 3 works fine. but I want to take (a) as a one string, then search it in b. for example: a="stack overflow"; b="tack stack over overflow"; the output is found, but actually (a) is not in (b) in the same order exactly, so the output should be not found. Thanks

Comment: i got your problem   it can be solved by little modification on solution 3  you can save the index of every character into an array and check if the index are sequential which means they are following each other then  its true   else it will be false                       how to check the sequential order is   you make a for loop and  check if the index of i   &  index of i+1  difference between them is 1  could you please mark the answer as accepted if you find it useful to you thanks

Comment: try this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm  it contain string functions    solution 4 is passing on the string taking all possible substrings of same size of the other string and comapring them   and this will work  also

Comment: Thank you for your help! But can you show me the modification on the code ? I get confused about the for loop. Thanks